# Problem with method type and variables

Tags: apex

I'm expecting some missing variables errors, for UserID and Method there is no incorrect signature: void get(String) of type String.
Could anyone help me with this?

I'm new in the area, but I've tried other methods and it doesn't stop with the Error.

This Cell is trying to PS activate the **UserID** as true or false and at the same time pulling the function.UserInfo.getUserId to get information when the user is logged in.

Since these functions are taking another cell (ABA) in VisualStudio Code.

```
public class GuiaService {
    public static Boolean GuiaCurrentUser(List<String> idGuia, List<String> loteList){
        try{
        TriggerHandler.bypass = true;
        List<Guia__c> listaGuias =Factory.getGuiasCurrentUser(idGuia);

        Map<String, Object> mapStringObject = new Map<String, Object>();  
        mapStringObject.put('ListaIdsGuia', (Object) idGuia);

        GuiaService alterarProprietario = new GuiaService();
        alterarProprietario.updateOnwerGuides(mapStringObject);  
        
        **String userId;
        if (String) 
        {
        data.get('UserOrQueueId') != null;
            userId = (String) data.get('UserOrQueueId');
         
        } else {
            userId = System.UserInfo.getUserId();**
        }
            update listaGuias;
            return true;
        } catch(Exception e){
            return false;
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao SFSE! Este site requer o uso de inglês. Isso foi traduzido pelo google.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! E por favor note que o idioma deste site é o inglês, então por favor poste em inglês. *[From Google Translate]*